# Iterating the streaming_content attribute on django FileResponse

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm working on an api with django rest framework, and I'm writing some unit tests to check critical operations. I'm trying to read the contents of a file after doing a get request

```
downloaded_file = self.client.get(textfile)
```

The problem is that the object returned is of type: django.http.response.FileResponse which inherits from [StreamingHttpResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/).

I'm trying to iterate over the streaming_content attribute, which supposedly is an iterator, but I cannot iterate, no method `next()`.

I inspected this object and what i get is map object. Any ideas on how to get the content from this request?

**Edit:**

Problem Solved

The returned object is a map, a map takes a function and a iterable:

https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#map

What I had to do was to cast the map to a list, access the first element of the list and convert from bytes to string. Not very elegant but it works.

```
list(response.streaming_content)[0].decode("utf-8")
```

Comment: For python 2.7 and django 1.8 the above only returns the first line.  but this will return all of the content: "".join([x for x in response.streaming_content])

Comment: is this one is relevant? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35647476/django-streaminghttpresponse-format-error

Comment: Indeed, the proposed solution is "not very elegant" :). No need to cast to `list` (see my answer).

Answer (score 14):

Here is how you extract the content from a `streaming_content` map:

```
content = downloaded_file.getvalue()
```

Looking at the code of the `getvalue()` method, we see that it just iterates over the answer content:

```
class StreamingHttpResponse(HttpResponseBase):
    ...
    def getvalue(self):
        return b''.join(self.streaming_content)
```